# Pandas: load records that span multiple lines

Tags: python, pandas, logging

I am looking for the standard pythonic way to load two common patterns in log files into a pandas dataframe.

Records that span multiple rows:

```
=REPORT==== 26-Jun-2018::18:30:00 ===
    column_1: some data
    column_2: {'maybe': 'json or something'}

=REPORT==== 26-Jun-2018::19:30:00 ===
    column_1: some data
    column_2: {'maybe': 'json or something',
               'and': 'maybe spanning multiple lines'}
```

Records that may span multiple rows:

```
2018-01-09 20:12:38,020 INFO logname: Examining 6668121 database
2018-01-09 20:13:00,020 ERROR logname: Caught an Exception
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test.py", line 1, in __main__
        None.do_the_thing()
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getDatabase'
```

For the first example, I expect to get a dataframe with columns like ['timestamp', 'column_1', 'column_2']

For the second, ['timestamp', 'log_level', 'logname', 'message text']

I'm fairly sure there is a way to denote separators for each record other than just the end of each line, and internal delimiters for each record.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think pandas does have an out-of-the-box way to accomplish what you want.

Here are the available methods for reading in dataframes from the [Doc on pandas I/O methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html):

> ```
> Format Type   Data Description    Reader      Writer
> text          CSV                 read_csv    to_csv
> text          JSON                read_json   to_json
> text          HTML                read_html   to_html
> text          Local clipboard     read_clipboard  to_clipboard
> binary        MS Excel            read_excel  to_excel
> binary        HDF5 Format         read_hdf    to_hdf
> binary        Feather Format      read_feather    to_feather
> binary        Parquet Format      read_parquet    to_parquet
> binary        Msgpack             read_msgpack    to_msgpack
> binary        Stata               read_stata      to_stata
> binary        SAS                 read_sas     
> binary        Python Pickle Format    read_pickle to_pickle
> SQL           SQL                 read_sql    to_sql
> SQL           Google Big Query    read_gbq    to_gbq
> ```

Both your examples don't follow the rules of the text formats: either csv, html, or json -- they're kind of a mismash of multiple formats. And to make matters more complicated, both your element separators and line separators vary from line-to-line.

From the [read_csv doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

If you want a complex column separator using a regex, then this forces pandas to use the python engine:

> sep : str, default ‘,’
>
> Delimiter to use. [...] In addition, separators longer than
>   1 character and different from '\s+' will be interpreted as regular
>   expressions and will also force the use of the Python parsing engine.
>   Note that regex delimiters are prone to ignoring quoted data. Regex
>   example: '\r\t'

Whereas the `lineterminator` arg can only be used with the C parser, and additionally can't be a regex:

> lineterminator : str (length 1), default None
>
> Character to break file into lines. Only valid with C parser.

You might be stuck writing your own parser, which is not ideal, as such things are error prone.